# Transform String to array using DOJO-AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dojo

I am having an issue, I am receiving from an external API that I don't have control a JSON message like below:

"{"searchResults":[{"resultNumber":1,"distance":0.06,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Chef Chen's Express","distanceUnit":"m","key":"1f9bcc0e-e03a-44d9-b034-c235c34997e2","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":2,"distance":0.07,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Prive","distanceUnit":"m","key":"ff5dcd5f-32ec-45fb-afd4-e66931ef84e2","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":3,"distance":0.07,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Bourbon Street Station","distanceUnit":"m","key":"a4f03b4d-12de-44ad-9ada-0f19beb34004","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":4,"distance":0.11,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Pasquale's Restaurant","distanceUnit":"m","key":"a05c487e-d81d-48e0-87a8-718db70ec366","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":5,"distance":0.12,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Palumbos Italian Eatery","distanceUnit":"m","key":"595afcbd-f61a-41ea-be2f-753648a8b7e8","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":6,"distance":0.12,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Zias At Red Door","distanceUnit":"m","key":"1393b154-0785-4ca8-8f3a-4190ab808817","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":7,"distance":0.13,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Dunes Mediterraneal Cuisine LLC","distanceUnit":"m","key":"3f8a43d1-7948-4653-bdbb-31222f24676f","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":8,"distance":0.13,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Bricco","distanceUnit":"m","key":"3f2e7653-1313-4e17-b70a-9c04a31a029f","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":9,"distance":0.13,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"Gingerbread Man Downtown","distanceUnit":"m","key":"2c36f5e0-801e-4f9e-91b6-7e9ae602a93d","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}},{"resultNumber":10,"distance":0.14,"sourceName":"mqap.ntpois","name":"International House","distanceUnit":"m","key":"2f328ca1-6fe4-44ec-964e-f7a6a73bfafd","fields":{"postal_code":"17101"}}],"origin":{"latLng":{"lng":-76.881821,"lat":40.259572},"adminArea4":"Dauphin County","adminArea5Type":"City","adminArea4Type":"County","adminArea5":"Harrisburg","street":"","adminArea1":"US","adminArea3":"PA","type":"s","displayLatLng":{"lng":-76.881821,"lat":40.259572},"linkId":282035911,"postalCode":"","sideOfStreet":"N","dragPoint":false,"adminArea1Type":"Country","geocodeQuality":"CITY","geocodeQualityCode":"A5XAX","adminArea3Type":"State"},"resultsCount":10,"hostedData":[{"tableName":"mqap.ntpois","extraCriteria":"group_sic_code=?","parameters":["581208"],"columnNames":["postal_code"]}],"totalPages":1,"info":{"statusCode":0,"copyright":{"text":"© 2015 MapQuest, Inc.","imageUrl":"http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif","imageAltText":"© 2015 MapQuest, Inc."},"messages":[]},"options":{"kmlStyleUrl":"http://www.mapquestapi.com/kml-default.kml","shapeFormat":"raw","ambiguities":true,"pageSize":10,"radius":1,"currentPage":1,"units":"m","maxMatches":10}}"

I have the restriction to be using DOJO-AJAX and CORS to send and receive the message but for some reason it comes as a plain string where I can't loop in this object using the code below:

renderReply : function(reply, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        var pois = new MQA.ShapeCollection();
                        var html = 'IDNAMEADDRESSZIPCATEGORYDISTANCE (miles)';

```
                    var jsonObj = dojo.toJson(reply);

                    // add POI markers and populate the search result table
                    for (i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
                        var result = reply[i];
```

As you can see I already tried to convert it with toJson but for some reason is worst is adding \ to the message and in reply[i] the first object is " " " quotes. I already tried accessing to the child with reply.searchResults but it says undefined object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's enough context here to give an ideal answer, but I would immediately point out that that string is *already* JSON, so `dojo.toJson` is stringifying what's already stringified.  You'd want `dojo.fromJson` (or, preferably, `dojo/json.parse` in newer versions of Dojo).

I would also point out that once you have this JSON string parsed, you presumably want to iterate over the `searchResults` property in the parsed object, not the object itself.

```
require(['dojo/json', ...], function(JSON, ...) {
    // Assuming `reply` contains the string:
    var replyObj = JSON.parse(reply);
    var results = replyObj.searchResults;
    for (var i = 0, l = results.length; i++) {
        // Do something with results[i]
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even my issue was on the wrong keyword, I need to do fromJSON as how I was receiving the object. Thanks!